# Adding another Host to a Cluster in Deis

Tags: amazon-ec2, deis

Is there a procedure for adding another host into an existing cluster? I'm using EC2.

I'm thinking it could be done by using CloudFormation again:

```
 aws cloudformation create-stack \
   --template-body "$(<deis.template)" \
   --stack-name deis-2 \
   --parameters "$(<cloudformation.json)"
```

Which would need a new stack name. That adds the new host.

Or just launch a new instance with the cli?

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-cfe125b8 --count 1 --instance-type m3.medium --key-name deis --security-groups sg-b7edc3c0,sg-c9edc3be
```

I'm guessing the host should be in both the coreos and deis security groups? And how does fleet know about the new host?

Then, we need to alter the hosts field?

```
deis clusters:info <cluster>

deis clusters:update <cluster> hosts=x,y,z
```

Anything else necessary? Is there another, easier way of doing it?

Comment: Using the AWS cli doesn't work, because DiscoveryURL isn't set. I haven't worked out how to subsequently set it.

Comment: You don't actually need to update the hosts field.  As long as 1 host in the list is available, jobs will be scheduled across the entire cluster (even if the hosts aren't listed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all we're dealing with here is CoreOS, it's completely possible to add new nodes to the cluster. The only requirement that you must do is to apply [the cloud-config template](https://github.com/deis/deis/blob/master/contrib/coreos/user-data) that you applied to every other node in the cluster to the new instance. See https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/cloud-providers/ec2/ for more info.

Comment: I'm actually going to be looking at doing this tomorrow so I might be able to write something up for the docs...if I'm successful.